# No Core Data entity subclasses during custom migrations

Tags: core-data, migration

I have a core data database. I'm performing a custom migration. I have a subclass of `NSEntityMigrationPolicy`. My policy's migration method `buildValueFromSectionFieldManagedObject:` is being called by a mapping rule : `FUNCTION($entityPolicy, "buildValueFromSectionFieldManagedObject:" , $source)`.

This part is actually working.

However, the implementation of `buildValueFromSectionFieldManagedObject:` uses methods in the custom entity `NSManagedObject` subclass of the `$source`, which is `Choice`.

The methods of `Choice` do not seem to be available to the migration function, and instead it gets just a vanilla `NSManagedObject`.

When I try to use `Choice` methods, I get an exception. If I `po` the choice in the debugger, I get something like this:

> <**NSManagedObject**: 0x600000281860> (**entity: Choice**; id: 0xd00000000038001a  ; data: )

Whereas, *out of a migration* I would usually see something like this:

> <**Choice**: 0x60800028bdb0> (**entity: Choice**; id: 0x6080002225a0  ; data: {

Is this just how it is, or is there some way that I can use the entity objects during migration?

Possibly relevant – this particular entity, `Choice`, is removed during this migration. It does not exist in the target managed object model, but *does* exist in the source managed object model. However, I don't think this is the case as other entity classes that are in the target model are also unavailable as that class during migration – they have class `NSManagedObject` and their entity methods are not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct, you only have access to basic `NSManagedObject`s during migration.

> **Three-Stage Migration**
>
> The migration process itself is in three stages. It uses a copy of the source and destination models in which the validation rules are disabled and the class of all entities is changed to NSManagedObject.

From: [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmMigrationProcess.html)

Comment: Thanks. … I think that in retrospect, having the entity objects in core data isn't a great plan. It seems to encourage bad architecture (managed objects  seep through to view controllers). The approach I've taken to solve this migration is to define protocols that expose the (legacy) interface necessary for migration. During migration I cast my `NSManagedObject` instances to `id <TheCorrectProtocol>` giving me type safety and property safety, and doesn't mislead me about what the objects are. I think this would be preferable to the entity classes generally – oh well.

Comment: Yes, Core Data does tend to infect your entire code base like that. Have you gotten the protocol to work? Because in my limited understanding of your issue, I'm not sure why it would work just by casting, although it will stop the compiler from complaining.

Comment: I did get it to work, and I'm fairly pleased with the outcome… So, I believe that even a vanilla `NSManagedObject` implements `respondsToSelector:` so you can read / write properties on it as you would a regular object and not need to use `setValue:forKey:`. I'll add another commend with a reference.

Comment: There's some reference about it in Sams ["Teach Yourself Cocoa"](https://books.google.cz/books?id=-tcuCrrmHo8C&pg=PT459&lpg=PT459&dq=does+nsmanagedobject+implement+respondstoselector&source=bl&ots=Hh1wjFa8Z0&sig=1HIA8gmx0dB-LA7H5M1lp9tmk5I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjplqPthYPSAhVL1hoKHTjmA50Q6AEIRDAH#v=onepage&q=does%20nsmanagedobject%20implement%20respondstoselector&f=false)

Comment: I might add a second answer showing the solution because it seems like a fairly good approach, imho. Thank you very much for confirming my initial suspicion though!

Comment: Ah, I thought you maybe had more complicated logic in your subclass that you wanted to access from the migration. In retrospect, it makes sense that a simple protocol works for you. I would definitely post another answer with details of how you handled your issue.

Comment: You're right, I _did_ have more complex logic in the subclass. I was able to factor this out in to a migration helper. And having the protocols made the helper easier to develop (code completion while typing) and safer (warnings / errors on incorrect message sends). Having done this, my feeling is that this is a better approach to interfacing with core data objects in general. It means you rely on its "magic" less and treat it as what it is. If you need magic, then you write the magic and understand its limitations – so its not magic :-)

Comment: Hi – FYI I added an answer with my protocol approach. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

[Dave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42104283/2547229) clarified that during a migration, core data object are only available as `NSManagedObject` instances. You don't get to use their Entity classes.

Worse, if you're using a tool like [mogenerator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42104283/2547229), then any handy logic that you've extended the entity classes with is inaccessible.

## Poor solutions

Working with an `NSManagedObject` directly feels dangerous to me. Using `[managedObject valueForKey:@"someKey"]` is verbose, but worse, there's no compiler checking that you've got your key name correct, so you might be asking for something `managedObject` doesn't have. There's also no compiler checking of the returned type either – it could be anything that you can put in to a managed object.

Slightly better is `[managedObject valueForKey: NSStringFromSelector(@selector(someKey))]` is safer, but horribly verbose and awkward, and still isn't *that* safe – lots of things might implement the method `someKey`.

You might also declare your keys as literals:

```
NSString *const someKey = @"someKey";
[managedObject valueForKey: someKey];
```

Again – this is slightly safer, less error prone and verbose, but you've got no guarantee still that *this* managed object has `someKey`.

None of these approaches will give us access to custom logic, either.

## Better solution

What I did instead of this was to define a `protocol` for the properties that *I know* my managed object has. Here's are examples for entities `Choice` and `ChoiceType`.

```
@protocol ChoiceProtocol
- (NSSet<id <ChoiceTypeProtocol> > *)choiceTypes;
- (NSNumber *)selected;
- (NSNumber *)order;
@end

@protocol ChoiceTypeProtocol
- (NSNumber *)selected;
- (NSString *)name;
- (NSString *)textCustom;
- (NSNumber *)order;
@end
```

Now in my migration code, instead of having a custom migration function similar to:

```
- (NSString *)migratedRepresentationOfChoice:(NSManagedObject *)choice;
```

I have:

```
- (NSString *)migratedRepresentationOfChoice:(id <ChoiceProtocol>)choice;
```

In the body of this function I can use `choice` exactly as I would any regular object. I get code completion as I type, I get the right syntax highlighting, the compiler will complain if I call a non existent method.

I also get *return type* checking, so the compiler will complain if I use the `NSNumber` property `selected` as an `NSString` or `NSSet`. And it'll also be helpful and suggest `NSNumber` methods as completions while I type.

## How about the logic?

This approach doesn't provide the logic you've added to entity classes.

In Swift you might be able to use a protocol extension to achieve that.

I was retiring these entities (hence the migration), so I moved the entity logic functions *I needed* in to a helper functions of my custom migration. As an  example `choice.orderedChoiceTypes` becomes `[self choiceOrderedChoiceTypes:choice]`.

In future I will probably avoid ever adding logic to `NSManagedObject` entities. I think it's probably a better plan to put any such logic in domain objects that you build from your managed objects. Further, I will probably avoid defining entity classes and instead *only* access `NSManagedObject` instances through a protocol as during the migration. It seems clean, simple, removes magic, and has benefits for testing – not just for migrations.

Comment: Great thorough answer!

Comment: Cheers, and thank you for pointing in the right direction @DaveWeston